# Mapping of dynamic environment

Tags: mobile-robot

I want to do path planning in dynamic environment in which obstacles keep changing. Could you suggest me good path planning algorithm for this? . Is D* algorithm suitable for me to achieve this in simulation?

Comment: D* is similar to A* very complicated to implement, I'd like to suggest an algorithm without any heuristics which is using the CPU with 100%.

Comment: So what are the algorithms you would suggest me for calculating shortest paths in dynamic environments other than D*?  Is D* lite easy to implement?. Is Potential field Algorithm a right choice for calculating shortest path?

Comment: If it's unclear which algorithm is the right one, a best practice method is to create a failed project. The idea is to show that D* isn't able to find the path for the robot because the map is too large. This creates a spot on the weakness.

Comment: VFH algorithm could do it!

Comment: Can shortest path be computed using potential field path planning algorithm? Or is it just for obstacle avoidance and navigative towards goal? As i studied potential field deals with attracrive/repulsive forces, its not for shortest path finding.

Comment: VFH is obstacle avoidance algorithm as i studied, i want the algorithm which computes shortest path in terms of distance towards the goal?

Comment: What you could do, is to start off your planning with A star, then when you start moving in the planned path when you encounter dynamic obstacles perform VFH to get around your dynamic obstacle. One you are clear, perform A Star again. This would be one way of doing it.

Comment: (1)Can i use potential field algorithm for dynamic obstacle avoidance instead of VFH as i have a good understanding of potential field algorithm with A* algorithm? (2) Is implementing D* lite complicated as compared to A*?

Comment: Hello, have you considered real-time RRT*? Its very simple to implement and scalable. As you move around the environemnt and update the map, the RRT* algorithm can replan a trajectory that avoids obstacles. Bug algorithms are also good for dynamic obstacle avoidance. Execute RRT* for global planning, when you encounter a obstacle execute tangent bug so the vehicle returns to the global path.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Saad. I'm afraid that on StackExchange *answers* need to answer the question, we are not a discussion forum, we are a place to ask questions and get answers. If you wish to discuss a question or answer you can use [chat], when you have [chat privileges](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat). You can comment when you have [comment privileges](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Please review [ask] and [about] for more information on how StackExchange works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [Vector Field Histogram](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~johannb/Papers/paper16.pdf) (VFH) algorithm for path planning in an environment with dynamic obstacles?